# Show data within the same column if data falls in the same time using Jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am developing an HTML web resource inorder to show the bookings but struck with a problem,please refer to the picture below.

There were two bookings, 
1.10:00 - 11:30 AM - Showing correct
2.11:30 - 12:00 PM - Incorrect, it should be  shown in the 11 AM block, any suggestions or clue to achieve this would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what problem you're trying to solve here, can you explain better - what's the expected input and outcome - and show code that you have tried to implement?

Comment: Without seeing some code then it's very hard for us to even help you. It's like giving a person a picture of your care and ask then why it's not working. No one can tell for sure.

Comment: Thank you..for taking time to respond to my query, got to know that it should be that way only...